# Extract subarray from collection of 2D coordinates?

Tags: python, arrays

In Python, I have a large 2D array containing data, and another Mx2 2D array containing a collection of M 2D coordinates of interest, e.g.

```
coords=[[150, 123], [151, 123], [152, 124], [153, 125]]
```

I would like to extract the Mx1 array containing the values of the data array at these coordinates (indices) locations. Obviously, `data[coords]` does not work.

I suspect there is an easy way to do that, but stackoverflow failed me up to now. Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: An example would be

```
data=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 1, 23, 40, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 20, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

coords=[[1,4],[2,4],[2,5],[5,3],[6,5]]
```

and the desired output would be

```
out=[2,23,40,5,20]
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample for what `data` looks like? Also, please add your desired output.

Comment: Well, my data are 1024x1024 arrays or integers, so I don't think it would make much sense to add it above. I'll add a mock example with desired output, though.

Comment: Just a sample would be fine.

Comment: M in the number of 2-D coordinates of interest I have, which can vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
In [73]: [data[i][j] for i,j in coords]
Out[73]: [2, 23, 40, 5, 20]
```

The result returned by the list comprehension is equivalent to

```
result = []
for i,j in coords:
    result.append(data[i][j])
```